# How to get relationship between asset and module while using bundle loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundle

```
require(`bundle!./components/${name}`)
```

bundle loader will generate files in my components dir,
[webpack output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NohRS.jpg)

will my program require one of them， It load a context file and another file for the component I require

[load scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2GeA.jpg)

How to get the relationship between my component like 'components/tab' and the asset file '17.17-a8a9d7162044e4556872.js'